Spring micrometer observe aspect dynamic tags
I am exploring using @observed aspect for method level simpler instrumentation code. This sample blog for the Observe API shows an example
https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3
@Observed(name = "user.name",
            contextualName = "getting-user-name",
            lowCardinalityKeyValues = {"userType", "userType2"})
    String userName(String userId) {

What if I want to pass userId method parameter as a high cardinality tag as part of metrics and span generated using the @Observed tag. Can the annotation take a dynamic method parameter into ?
Or should I be writing some observationhandler to do this?

Right now you can do this one-liner:
observationRegistry.getCurrentObservation().highCardinalityKeyValue("userId", userId);

ObservationHandler is for producing an output from Observability data so I would not use it for this purpose but you might be able to use an ObservationFilter if this information is available in the Context.
You can also open an issue/PR to add support for this, we already have similar for Timer: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/3727

Will this tag get added to all the metrics generated by the observation as well? Not seeing the tag getting added. Would this one liner go inside the :
String userName(String userId) {
observationRegistry.getCurrentObservation().highCardinalityKeyValue("userId", userId);

No, high cardinality tags mustn't be added to metrics, if you want to add data to metrics too, use lowCardinalityKeyValue(...). But userId is usually not low cardinality. You can learn more about this here: https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/
